# Android: How to differentiate with SD Card mount in the two situations: 1) when device is booted, 2) when SD Card is mounted while device was on?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how can I differentiate between these conditions programmatically. I have different use cases to handle in both situations.

How to differentiate with SD Card mount in the two situations: 1) when device is booted, 2) when SD Card is mounted while device was on?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you have doing so?

Comment: The Intent in both cases is Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED. But when a device is restarted, I don't want to perform the same actions as when I mount the SD card when device is on.

Comment: We already knew that. You explained nothing about the difficulties you encounter doing so.

Comment: I need to know how can I differentiate between the two cases. Is there a condition/value I can check?